# AlertDialog button text color with support library v24.2.1

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-library, android-alertdialog, androiddesignsupport

I am having problems with the AlertDialog. The buttons doesn't use the accentColor to set the button text color any more.

I am using the newest support library, v24.2.1. I am styling my dialogs in my styles.xml the following way:

```
<style name="Base.Theme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/Widget.DialogStyle</item>
    <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/Widget.DialogStyle</item>
</style>
```

and the Widget.DialogStyle looks like this:

```
<style name="Widget.DialogStyle" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:colorAccent" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/primaryText</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/primaryText</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/backgroundColor</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceLarge">@color/primaryText</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
</style>
```

On app API's lower than 24 the dialog buttons are colored with the colorAccent but on API 24 this is no more the behaviour (the text is black, should be orange). See the following [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8CVb.png).

Is there anybody that knows how to get the accentColor back on the buttons?
Thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For some `AlertDialog` implementations, the buttons are contained in a ButtonBar *and* take their style from `buttonBarButtonStyle`. So you have to override the settings you inherit from the parent theme (`Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert`).

Add the following item to `Widget.DialogStyle`:

```
<item name="buttonBarButtonStyle">@style/MyButtonStyle</item>
```

and add another style named `MyButtonStyle` like this:

```
<style name="MyButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless">
    <!-- Set background drawable and text size of the buttons here
    <item name="android:background">@color/my_dialog_dark</item>-->
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>

    <!-- this is the button text color!    -->
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/primaryColor</item>
</style>
```

**EDIT**

Thanks to kirtan403 for pointing this out: you can also use another parent style for the buttons if `Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless` does not meet your requirements.

An [example by nicola.v...@icapps.com](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=220699#c12) using `Widget.AppCompat.Button.ButtonBar.AlertDialog` as parent style for the buttons can be found under the AOSP Issue 220699: **colorAccent not applied to AlertDialog buttons on Android N**.

Comment: @Christian Leicht Jørgensen - Worked for me, both with standalone AlertDialog and AlertDialog in DialogFragment. Now I really hope it works for you as well

Comment: Did this change get documented anywhere?

Comment: @Austyn Mahoney - if there is an official document covering this (or even better covering version dependent styling of diverse types of dialog in general), I'd love to read it.

Comment: I learned how to style dialogs mainly from a widely quoted [off site resource](http://joerg-richter.fuyosoft.com/?p=181). It's a little outdated by now, but it shows that in some android versions the ButtonBar may/should be styled to achieve the desired result. So I made an educated guess, that's all. As long as I can't get official statements I'm happy if I can get feedback from people using a device - I only have an emulator so far.

Comment: @0X0nosugar I ask because the implementation seems to have changed in recent support library update. Frustrating to have my styles buttons randomly disappear. I have an accent color set for a reason.

Comment: @Austyn Mahoney - I absolutely agree: it's frustrating that SO is the source where one may stumble across such an important piece of information if one is lucky. But to make sure I got it right: did the accent color disappear on a device running N? Or is it some lower API level and you only changed the library version?

Comment: @0X0nosugar I'm not entirely sure, but the buttons only seem to be default styled on `7.x`, so the accent color must not be applied correctly to dialogs when using Support Library `v24.2.x`. We actually set a theme dialog style with our accent color and it fixed the dialog issue, no `buttonBarStyle` necessary.

Comment: Borderless button style adds extra space in the buttons. Instead use this solution: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=220699#c12

Comment: @kirtan403 - thanks for the link! I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure you are importing the correct `AlertDialog`:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog
```

Also try inflating the dialog with another `AlertDialog.Builder` constructor:

```
android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder#Builder(android.content.Context, int)
```

which means, the second parameter is the style of the dialog:

```
mDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.Widget.DialogStyle).create();
```

EDIT:

Sharing the code, that I use to show alert Dialog:

```
public AlertDialog showSimpleDialog(Context context, String title, String message, String btnOk, DialogInterface.OnClickListener handler) {
    if (mDialog != null && mDialog.isShowing()) {
        mDialog.dismiss();
        mDialog = null;
    }
    mDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.AppTheme_Dialog).create();
    mDialog.setTitle(title);
    mDialog.setMessage(message);
    mDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, btnOk, handler);
    mDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    mDialog.show();
    return mDialog;
}
```

and the style:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Dialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item> //blue
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/primary_text_material_light</item> //black
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">97%</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">97%</item>
</style>
```

and the buttons are blue. Tested on emulator API 24.

Comment: I just tested using emulators: One of my apps and also OP's code. Both use the primary text color for the button text color when running on Nougat. This may be another Nougat bug :( Yesterday someone posted about a problem with animations, today this...

Comment: Therefore I advise you to use support library for such things as it is independent of system version styles.

Comment: Thanks but that's precisely what I am doing :) Did you test your answer on Nougat? I really think it's a bug. Non-AppCompat AlertDialog: no problem. DialogFragment: no problem. AppCompat AlertDialog: text color on Button is textColorPrimary (from the Dialog style). It would be nice if you could run your own test using the code you posted and OP's style.xml  and let us know whether you can confirm the issue or not.

Comment: I cannot confirm it. I works perfectly on Nougat. That is why I posted the answer. Maybe the branded phone causes problem, as it's system may not be 100% compliant with google version.

Comment: Thanks - I can only test on an emulator, so maybe there's something wrong with the emulator for Nougat. I'm really happy to know because otherwise I would have to change all the AlertDialogs in my own app ASAP to DialogFragments.

Comment: I have tested this on both my Nexus 5X with API 24 and on an emulator with API 24. The behaviour is the same. The text remains black.

I am importing: android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog and setting the style in the Builders contrstructor doesn't change anything.